# TFS Build Definition Dropdown Menu

Tags: tfsbuild, build-definition

VS2012 TFS2012

I followed [this](http://blogs.msmvps.com/molausson/2014/06/30/how-to-add-an-enum-to-a-tfs-build-definition-2/) simple guide to create drop down menu in build definition. My goal is to have two drop downs, one with 20 selections and being able to select multiple options, second with 70 and pick only one.

After adding more than two options to enum, selecting and deselecting doesn't work properly. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Workflow.ActivityHelpers
{
public enum Enums
    {

        Internal,
        Public,
        Failed,
        Another,
        YetAnother
    }
}
```

I select Another and Internal deselects , and Public and Failed selects. With each click I get different combination of selected\unselected options.

EDIT:
Adding pictures
Open DropDown 
Only Internal2 is selected(TOO low rep to post more than 2 links)
Clicked Another
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ksfH.png)
Now 3 Are selected.

Refer to other post for answer.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot for the drop menu? What's the detail phenomenon of working not properly? Did you want to use Multiple selection or just single selection?

Comment: one with 20 selections and being able to select multiple options, second with 70 and pick only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I end up doing is something like this:
[custom type for an argument](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/17/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-6-Use-custom-type-for-an-argument.aspx)

I needed to get data XML. For multiple selection I used dynamic checkboxes that were created from xml sections. For single selection I went with combobox.

Important Note. To actually make this work and Build read data U need to change

return value;

to

```
 class CredentialEditor : UITypeEditor 
{ 

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value) 
    { 
        string selected = null;
        if (provider != null) 
        { 
            IWindowsFormsEditorService editorService = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService)); 

            if (editorService != null) 
            { 
                Credential credential = value as Credential; 

                using (CredentialDialog dialog = new CredentialDialog()) 
                { 
                    dialog.UserName = credential.UserName; 
                    dialog.Password = credential.Password; 

                    if (editorService.ShowDialog(dialog) == DialogResult.OK) 
                    { 
                        credential.UserName = dialog.UserName; 
                        credential.Password = dialog.Password; 
                        selected = dialog.UserName
                    } 
                } 
            } 

        } 

        return new Credentials() { UserName = selected}; 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The guide is using "if... then... else". This is suit for two options. Please change to the correct code. And make sure the variable type which can supported for multiple selection.

Comment: I should of said that before, I do not use If Statement. All I want is to get Selected Enum When build is Run. I did different way. Refer to post.